# CSS, Bootstrap: make element auto arrange position to fit the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have series of element which should look like this in a big screen:

```
[-1-][---2----][-3-][-4-]
```

However when the screen is smaller,the elements should auto adjust its position to fit the screen (each element width and height cannot change):

```
[-1-][-3-]
[---2----]
[-4-]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Comment: Which version of Twitter Bootstrap?  This strikes me as very difficult in Bootstrap 3 but trivial in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: Iam using boostrap 3.

Comment: Would it be problematic (functionality or performance) to duplicate `[-3-]` in the code?  The idea would be to have one visible and the other hidden at all breakpoints.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem. However, I do not known before hand which element will be the bigger one, some time it's number 4, some time it's number 3, ...

Comment: Sounds like you need something more like the [masonry plugin](https://masonry.desandro.com/).  This will not be possible with simple Bootstrap or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should add classes:

```
col-xs-6 to 1

col-xs-12 to 2

col-xs-6 to 3

col-xs-6 to 4
```

But height won't be equal because elements must change height to fit to screen size. Of course You can add `max-height` in CSS but it's hard to say how this will looks like.

Comment: It's not working. The element is displayed in 3 lines: (1), (2), and (3,4)

Comment: impossible that col-xs-6 became col-xs-12 on mobiles with width <767 ... You must doing something wrong in other place